# Javascript/JQuery browser testing frame work for IE9/FF/Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, testing, google-chrome

I apologize if this question was asked already before but I could not find an answer on google.

I am looking for a testing plugin for each browser, where I could simply record a test (click on a variety of things) and then simply run this test just by clicking 'run test'. The best if I could write some code about what sort of answers I require (i.e. generated final html), but if that is possible it is ok.

The reason I can't use stuff like JUnit etc. is because my code uses external webservices (such as payment on an external server, that I can't access) and I am redirected to different pages during the test, so I assume it has to be a test plugin.

If the plugins would be intergrated with Visual Studio 2010 (or at least the IE plugin) it would be awesome, but I can live without it.

I am reading into iMacros (Chrome, but unfortunately beta) and Selenium(Firefox), but I wanted to know what is the mostly standart way to do that (I assume it was done for ages now). Additionally I need one for IE9, which I did not find yet.

Thanks in advance,
Jozef

ps. I create AJAX heavy webpage, so simple URL based testing is not enough (like AdobeBrowser lab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is quite good for web browser automated testing and the latest version works with almost all versions of IE (7 - 9) (I can't view the documentation at work at the moment) and Firefox 3 - 8, and Chrome 12 upwards.

There are some good examples on the selenium website and on the http://code.google.com/p/selenium/ site too.

(For the Chrome browser you'll also need to download the ChromeiumServer

Here's some rough and ready sourcecode I've been messing about a while back

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string Path = @"H:\Selenium\chromedriver_win_16.0.902.0\";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestMethodChromeViaServer();

            WebBrowser(TestMethodFf());
            WebBrowser(TestMethodIe());
            WebBrowser(TestMethodChromeDefault());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the code in the browser.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="webDriver">The Web Driver to use to initiate a web browser.</param>
        public static void WebBrowser(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://nerddinner.com/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=%2F#");

            IWebElement query = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
            query.Submit();

            var foo = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[for='UserName']"));

            webDriver.Quit();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Launches Google Chrome via the service so multiple tests can be run before closing the service.
        /// </summary>
        public static void TestMethodChromeViaServer()
        {
            var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path);
            service.Start();

            IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.ServiceUrl, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());

            WebBrowser(driver);

            service.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Web Driver using Google Chrome.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Web driver with ChromeDriver setup to the correct path.</returns>
        public static IWebDriver TestMethodChromeDefault()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Path);

            return driver;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Web Driver using Firefox.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Web driver with FirefoxDriver profile setup.</returns>
        public static IWebDriver TestMethodFf()
        {
            var foxProfile = new FirefoxProfile
                {
                    AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true
                };

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(foxProfile);

            return driver;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Web Driver using Internet Explorer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Web driver with InternetExplorerDriver setup.</returns>
        public static IWebDriver TestMethodIe()
        {
            //// Must set the protected mode on each zone to be the same (on or off), under tools -> security tab
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            return driver;
        }
    }
}
```